# Evaluating $\int^1_0 \frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx$ using Leibniz's integral formula

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I read a wikipedia article about Leibniz integral rule and its [applications](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Other_problems_to_solve).

It stated that $\int^1_0 \frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx$ can be evaluated with this rule, so I tried it.

I started by:

$$f(\alpha)=\int^1_0\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x}dx$$

$$\int^1_0 \frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx=f(1)$$

$$f(0)=0$$

$$f'(\alpha)=\int^1_0\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x} dx$$

$$=\ln \alpha \int^1_0 \frac{x^\alpha}{\ln x}dx$$

I was stuck here, and tried:

$$f''(\alpha)=\frac 1\alpha \int^1_0\frac{x^\alpha}{\ln x}dx+ {(\ln \alpha)}^2\int^1_0\frac{x^\alpha}{\ln x}dx$$

$$=\left(\frac 1\alpha + {(\ln \alpha)}^2\right)f'(\alpha)$$

$$\therefore \frac{f''(\alpha)}{f'(\alpha)}=\left(\frac 1\alpha + {(\ln \alpha)}^2\right)$$

$$\therefore \ln |f'(\alpha)|=\ln \alpha +\alpha {(\ln\alpha)}^2-2\alpha\ln\alpha+2\alpha+C$$

$$|f'(\alpha)|=\alpha e^{\alpha {(\ln\alpha)}^2-2\alpha\ln\alpha+2\alpha+C}$$

Stuck again!

How can I evaluate $\int^1_0 \frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx$ using Leibniz's integral formula?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a mistake in the derivative under the integral. The derivative is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}x^\alpha = x^\alpha \ln x$, not $x^\alpha \ln \alpha$. The integral then becomes
$$f'(\alpha) = \int_0^1 x^\alpha \, dx $$
which is much easier.

Comment: Thank you! I did a noob thing..

Comment: You are welcome. And don't worry, everybody does noob things from time to time...

Comment: So is answer $\ln 2$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.